# What is the difference between an automatic transmission and an automated manual transmission?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, power-engineering

What is the difference between an automatic transmission (AT) and an automated manual transmission (AMT)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In answering this question I'm assuming you already know the difference between an Automatic Transmission (AT) and a Manual Transmission (MT).

---

### Conventional Automatic Transmission (AT)

- Minimal to no power interruption
- Automatic moving-off
- Various gear ratios
- Efficiency: 90-95%

---

### Automated Manual Transmission (AMT)

Functionality is the same as a Z-speed manual transmission in constant-mesh or synchromesh but the process of shifting gears and moving off are automated.

- Power interruption like a manual transmission (MT)
- Automatic moving-off
- Efficiency: 92-97% (pretty much the same as a MT)
- Reputation for poor shift quality and reliability

There are more - I wasn't sure if you were looking for functional differences or characteristics. See the reference I've provided for more info - it is a fantastic textbook.

---

Reference:

Automotive Transmissions: Fundamentals, Selection, Design and Application (Naunheimer et al.)

Comment: I still don't understand, but I'm not very well versed in the terminology of transmissions. ; )  I'll leave it up to the original questioner to determine if their question is answered.

Comment: @hazzey It is a pretty broad question - not sure if the OP is looking for a detailed answer on how their functionality differs or not.

Comment: It was just a general question.